# Why Maven doesn't install dependencies in multimodule project?

Tags: java, maven

My project structure (multi module) is like this

```
parent
    projectA
    projectB
    ... other modules
```

`parent` also actually has a parent (Spring Boot).

I have set up a Jenkins jobs to compile & test on every commit, so it runs:

```
mvn -f pom.xml clean install
```

And that all works fine. `ProjectB` depends on `ProjectA` (which is like a common classes type of project) and is a Spring boot application. So the dependency information is the regular:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>Group</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjectA</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

`ProjectB` has a separate job in Jenkins to build the deployable jar file and deploy it to server. So the command there is:

```
mvn -f ProjectB/pom.xml clean install antrun:run
```

This fails with a message like:

```
[WARNING] The POM for Group:ProjectB:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project host-api: Could not resolve dependencies for project Group:ProjectB:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: Group:ProjectA:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT...
```

Now I can resolve this by doing a `mvn install` in the `ProjectA` directory - I've tested this and it does resolve the issue.

But my question is **why should I have to**? Shouldn't Maven figure out it should be installing the jar in the local repo?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need a Maven repo, for example Sonatype Nexus, to store the compiled artefacts. You would then run `mvn clean deploy` to push the finished artefacts to the (separately configured) repo. Currently, there is no "store" for the artefacts between jobs so it cannot find them.

Comment: @BoristheSpider thanks but i don't want to deploy to a repo as such, I just want it to go into my local `~/.mx` repo so that `ProjectB` can build. Or are you saying that's the only way? Highly likely i've misunderstood here, but I thought if I'm building locally the the local repo is all I need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR Tell maven about the structure of your project.

When you run the command

```
mvn -f pom.xml clean install
```

Then maven uses [the reactor](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) to work out the order of the modules, something like the following is output:

> [INFO] Reactor build order:
>   [INFO]   ProjectA
>   [INFO]   ProjectB

So Maven first builds project A, then builds project B.

When you run the command:

```
mvn -f ProjectB/pom.xml clean install antrun:run
```

Then you have a problem; maven isn't starting from the parent - it's starting from a child. It's not told about the hierarchy of projects needed to be built first.

If you want to build a single project from a maven multimodule project, along with dependencies you should use:

```
mvn -f pom.xml -pl ProjectB -am install antrun:run
```

Where:

- `-pl ProjectB` is the "project list" option, it tells maven to build these specific projects
- `-am` is the "also make" option, it tells maven to build any projects that the projects in `pl` are dependant on

Answer (score 0):

Specify the dependencies build part when you run the build:

[Guide to Working with Multiple Modules](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)

Comment: Thanks, I tried `--projects ProjectA --also-make-dependents` but same error occurrs

Comment: @user2393012 you used `mvn -f ProjectB/pom.xml --projects ProjectA --also-make-dependents` didn't you. See my comment on your answer...

Answer (score 0):

So I suppose the rule is, always build the parent project first and then run goals on subprojects afterwards.

The fix for me was to run `clean install` on the parent project first and then have a second build configuration in Jenkins that ran `-f ProjectB/pom.xml antrun:run`

Comment: Further, don't use `-f`. Maven uses the pom in the current directory by default. You also want to tell maven the dependencies of the project. So what you want is `mvn -pl ProjectB -am`. This will allow maven to read the parent pom, and the read the dependencies of `ProjectB`, the `am` flag asks maven to also make projects in the dependency tree. Basically, let Maven do its job and stop trying to outsmart it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks, Jenkins puts the `-f` in, and it has to be there because the parent projected is nested in a folder structure. I will try `mvn -pl ProjectB -am` - thanks!

Comment: @BoristheSpider you're right, that worked and is much cleaner. Put it an answer and I'll mark it is the right one